# How I include my chart.js script to admin lte

Tags: javascript, html, charts

I want to create admin page using adminLTE. I need to insert chart using chart.js into my page on adminlte. But when I tried to insert my code, the chart is not showing, just the blank.

Then I need to edit adminlte chartjs script, but the chart still not showing up.

This is my code on chartjs

```
 <script>
var myChart1 = document.getElementById('myChart1').getContext('2d');

// Global Options
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Lato';
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 18;
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#777';

var massPopChart = new Chart(myChart1, {
  type:'bar', // bar, horizontalBar, pie, line, doughnut, radar, polarArea
  data:{
    labels:['Boston', 'Worcester', 'Springfield', 'Lowell', 'Cambridge', 'New Bedford'],
    datasets:[{
      label:'Population',
      data:[
        617594,
        181045,
        153060,
        106519,
        105162,
        95072
      ],
      //backgroundColor:'green',
      backgroundColor:[
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.6)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.6)',
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)'
      ],
      borderWidth:1,
      borderColor:'#777',
      hoverBorderWidth:3,
      hoverBorderColor:'#000'
    }]
  },
  options:{
    title:{
      display:true,
      text:'Largest Cities In Massachusetts',
      fontSize:25,
      responsive: true
    },
    legend:{
      display:true,
      position:'right',
      labels:{
        fontColor:'#000'
      }
    },
    layout:{
      padding:{
        left:50,
        right:0,
        bottom:0,
        top:0
      }
    },
    tooltips:{
      enabled:true
    }



  }
});

var myChart2 = document.getElementById('myChart2').getContext('2d');


var massPopChart = new Chart(myChart2, {
  type:'horizontalBar', // bar, horizontalBar, pie, line, doughnut, radar, polarArea
  data:{
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets:[{
      label:'Population',
      data:[
        617594,
        181045,
        153060,
        106519,
        105162,
        95072
      ],
      //backgroundColor:'green',
      backgroundColor:[
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.6)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.6)',
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)'
      ],
      borderWidth:1,
      borderColor:'#777',
      hoverBorderWidth:3,
      hoverBorderColor:'#000'
    }]
  },
  options:{
    title:{
      display:true,
      text:'Largest Cities In Massachusetts',
      fontSize:25
    },
    legend:{
      display:true,
      position:'right',
      labels:{
        fontColor:'#000'
      }
    },
    responsive: true,
    tooltips:{
      enabled:true
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Here's the html script

```
<div class="box box-primary">
    <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h3 class="box-title">Area Chart</h3>

        <div class="box-tools pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="chart">
            <canvas id="myChart1"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box box-primary">
    <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h3 class="box-title">Chart Bar</h3>

        <div class="box-tools pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="chart">
            <canvas id="myChart2"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Which version of chartjs did you used? I've tested your code without changes it works fine. Maybe you've forgot to add js file. Please check your console.log for errors.

```js
var myChart1 = document.getElementById('myChart1').getContext('2d');

// Global Options
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Lato';
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 18;
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#777';

var massPopChart = new Chart(myChart1, {
  type:'bar', // bar, horizontalBar, pie, line, doughnut, radar, polarArea
  data:{
    labels:['Boston', 'Worcester', 'Springfield', 'Lowell', 'Cambridge', 'New Bedford'],
    datasets:[{
      label:'Population',
      data:[
        617594,
        181045,
        153060,
        106519,
        105162,
        95072
      ],
      //backgroundColor:'green',
      backgroundColor:[
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.6)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.6)',
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)'
      ],
      borderWidth:1,
      borderColor:'#777',
      hoverBorderWidth:3,
      hoverBorderColor:'#000'
    }]
  },
  options:{
    title:{
      display:true,
      text:'Largest Cities In Massachusetts',
      fontSize:25,
      responsive: true
    },
    legend:{
      display:true,
      position:'right',
      labels:{
        fontColor:'#000'
      }
    },
    layout:{
      padding:{
        left:50,
        right:0,
        bottom:0,
        top:0
      }
    },
    tooltips:{
      enabled:true
    }



  }
});

var myChart2 = document.getElementById('myChart2').getContext('2d');


var massPopChart = new Chart(myChart2, {
  type:'horizontalBar', // bar, horizontalBar, pie, line, doughnut, radar, polarArea
  data:{
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets:[{
      label:'Population',
      data:[
        617594,
        181045,
        153060,
        106519,
        105162,
        95072
      ],
      //backgroundColor:'green',
      backgroundColor:[
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.6)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.6)',
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)'
      ],
      borderWidth:1,
      borderColor:'#777',
      hoverBorderWidth:3,
      hoverBorderColor:'#000'
    }]
  },
  options:{
    title:{
      display:true,
      text:'Largest Cities In Massachusetts',
      fontSize:25
    },
    legend:{
      display:true,
      position:'right',
      labels:{
        fontColor:'#000'
      }
    },
    responsive: true,
    tooltips:{
      enabled:true
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="box box-primary">
<div class="box-header with-border">
    <h3 class="box-title">Area Chart</h3>

    <div class="box-tools pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box-body">
    <div class="chart">
        <canvas id="myChart1"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="box box-primary">
<div class="box-header with-border">
    <h3 class="box-title">Chart Bar</h3>

    <div class="box-tools pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box-body">
    <div class="chart">
        <canvas id="myChart2"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @thunderfly, when I create a single page, it works fine. But when I tried to insert code to adminlte page, the chart is not showing

Comment: there any error output in console? you can try to latest version of chartjs cdn file for test dont use adminLte chartjs file. After you can download and replace current chartjs files in adminLte plugins. Chartjs official site examples doesnt work with old chart codes.